# How to judge a channel/chat is private( Telethon)?

Tags: python, telethon

I want to export my channel list which could include some other information. I want to judge a dialogs is it private which i have joined, but i don't known how to deal this problem.

I try to use `iter.dialogs()` to get my all dialogs, but it's `dialog.entity` don't have member is `is_private`, i don't known how to get the infomation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the dialog's username to "judge" whether your channel or group is private.

```
if dialog.entity.username is not None:
   print("Dialog is public")
else:
   print("Dialog is private")
```